# How to create an object from JSON file stored in the same place as the script in javaScript?

Tags: javascript, json

I am trying to make my application (a game) load the data that specify the contents of the different levels from .json files stored on the server or in the folder of the webapp. The script stores these contents in the object 'levelcontents' which needs to be completely reloaded every time a new level is started. This is the function that loads a level (level 0 is the main menu):

```
    var levelcontents;
    function loadLevel(l)
    {
        //just ignore the next line
        level = l;

        switch (l){
        case 0://here 'levelcontents' should get the attributes and methods specified in level0.json 
        break;
        case 1://here 'levelcontents should get the attributes and methods specified in level1.json
        break;
        }
    }
```

So, for example, when loadLevel(0) has been called, and afterwards levelcontents.draw() is called, the draw() function specific to level 0 (which the game got from level0.json) should be executed. 
I tried out some things already, but I couldn't find anything that I could get to work. If someone could explain how exactly I need to do this, preferably just in javaScript I would really appreciate it.

As requested the contents of level0.json (not very relevant):

```
{
"draw": function(){
ctx.clearRect(0,0,960,720);
ctx.fillStyle = "#000000";
},
"load": function(){
if (beginning = 0) {erasePrev};
loadHTML('button','level1Button',"position:absolute; top:100px; left:200px;",'LEVEL I','loadLevel(1)',false,false);
loadHTML('a','howtoplayhref',"position:absolute; top:100px; left:100px;",'how to play',false,false,'howtoplay.html');
},
"clear": function(){
removeHTML(level1Button);
removeHTML(howtoplayhref);
}
}
```

Comment: If the levelcontents was array of all levels you could do simply levelcontents[l].draw() without the need for switch statement

Comment: Show us the structure of `levelcontents` object.

Comment: @SergeSeredenko the structure is not specified yet. I am trying to have the structure specified according to the contents of a .json file, which can be level0.json, level1.json, level2.json and so on, depending on the value of the parameter l.